# Azure Active Directory - Clear Token Cache

Tags: azure-active-directory

I use below code to aquire a token to authenticate against an API. Is there a way to clear token cache every time AcquireTokenAsync call is made?

```
AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = null;
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true);
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
authenticationResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(apiResourceId, credential);
```

Comment: You could try this `authContext.TokenCache.Clear();`

Comment: Why do you want it to skip cache? Are you changing the permissions the app has a lot?

Comment: @SunnySun Thanks it worked. Needed to test list of keys.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clear token cache that is made by the Acquire TokenAsync call, you could use the method `authContext.TokenCache.Clear();` to make this.